# SIP: how to know, for which REFER the NOTIFY came?

Tags: sip, notify, refer

Suppose, we have a following dialog:

```
Agent A                  Agent B
  |                        |
  |   F1 REFER             |
  |----------------------->|
  |        F2 202 Accepted |
  |<-----------------------|
  |        F3 NOTIFY       |
  |<-----------------------|
  |  F4 200 OK             |
  |----------------------->|
  |                        |
  |                        |
  |                        |------->
  |                        |  (whatever)
  |                        |<------
  |                        |
  |         F5 NOTIFY      |
  |<-----------------------|
  |   F6 200 OK            |
  |----------------------->|
  |                        |
  |                        |
  |                        |
  |   F7 REFER             |
  |----------------------->|
  |        F8 202 Accepted |
  |<-----------------------|
  |        F9 NOTIFY       |
  |<-----------------------|
  |  F10 200 OK            |
  |----------------------->|
  |                        |------->
  |                        |  (something different)
  |                        |<------
  |                        |
  |         F11 NOTIFY     |
  |<-----------------------|
  |   F12 200 OK           |
  |----------------------->|
  |                        |
  |                        |
```

with two REFERs (taken from [RFC 3515](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3515.txt))

I get the NOTIFY request for each REFER, like this:

```
NOTIFY sip:192.168.1.39:5062;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.249;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bKyZ09F8gtB6rtQ;received=192.168.1.249
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "Extension 1200" <sip:1200@192.168.1.249>;tag=7ytSSBvaBeN5H
To: <sip:1201@192.168.1.39:5062>;tag=25b9a9ba-f249-4e21-a25a-c2ed578c5101
Call-ID: f94d6be3-edfc-122f-ebb0-000c29da7e39
CSeq: 25832274 NOTIFY
Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@192.168.1.249:5060>
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.0.head-git-5e4a514 2012-03-10 22-56-29 -0500
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,OPTIONS,MESSAGE,UPDATE,INFO,REGISTER,REFER,NOTIFY,PUBLISH,SUBSCRIBE
Supported: timer,precondition,path,replaces
Event: refer;id=1
Allow-Events: talk,hold,presence,dialog,line-seize,call-info,sla,include-session-description,presence.winfo,message-summary,refer
Subscription-State: terminated;reason=noresource
Content-Type: message/sipfrag;version=2.0
Content-Length: 16

SIP/2.0 200 OK
```

which notifies me, that the REFER was successfull.

The question is: in the NOTIFY, how do I know, for which REFER it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same RFC:

> 2.4.6 Multiple REFER Requests in a Dialog
>
> A REFER creates an implicit subscription sharing the dialog
>      identifiers in the REFER request.  If more than one REFER is issued
>      in the same dialog (a second attempt at transferring a call for
>      example), the dialog identifiers do not provide enough information to
>      associate the resulting NOTIFYs with the proper REFER.
>
> Thus, for the second and subsequent REFER requests a UA receives in a
>      given dialog, it MUST include an id parameter[2] in the Event header
>      field of each NOTIFY containing the sequence number (the number from
>      the CSeq header field value) of the REFER this NOTIFY is associated
>      with.  This id parameter MAY be included in NOTIFYs to the first
>      REFER a UA receives in a given dialog.  A SUBSCRIBE sent to refresh
>      or terminate this subscription MUST contain this id parameter.